# Legion 5 laptop is permanently disconnected from wifi after suspending

Tags: networking, suspend, hibernate

I created an account for this.

I have a brand new gaming laptop and am trying to install Ubuntu on it, but it keeps permanently disconnecting the wifi after I close it. Only when I power off then power back on the wifi adapter connects.

I have tried this solution: [Wifi lost after a resume from hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557043/wifi-lost-after-a-resume-from-hibernation)
(though I have wlp4s0 instead of wlan0 so I did that)

and tried all of these things from **chatGPT**:

[image: chatgpt-solution-1]

[image: chatgpt-solution-3]

[image: chatgpt-solution-3]

Although with 3. I tried to do it, but it kept on exiting and saying the job failed, I tried doing `/bin/bash/` instead of `/bin/sh` too.

Kind of at a dead-end

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; so we don't yet know what options are available to you. If you're using a LTS release, kernel stack choices exist; these change kernel & thus kernel modules change too (commonly called *drivers*). Some of the details you posted are also using *deprecated* commands; so is your system very dated?  If it's a new device, you should be using a new OS with newer kernel stack (*but you gave no details*).